# Picard's Theorem for $y' = \frac{x+1}{x^2-y}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Hello and Happy New Year. I am studying ODEs and right now I am working on Picard's Theorem. I know that if I have an IVP i.e. $y' = e^x - y^2, \ y(0)=1$ then I follow the next steps

1. Let us consider $f(x,y) = e^x - y^2$ and $D = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2: |x| \leq a , \ |y-1| \leq b, \ a,b>0 \}$
2. $D$ is closed, $f$ is continous on $D$ and a bound of $f$ is $M = (b+2+e^a)^2 + e^a$
3. From the relation $|\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}| \leq ...\leq k$, then $f$ is $y$-Lipschitz with constant $k$.

So Picard's Theorem holds for $|x| \leq h = \min \{a, \frac{b}{(b+2+e^a)^2 + e^a}\}$.

But, in another problem $y' = \frac{x+1}{x^2-y}, \ y(x_0)=x_0$, if we take the function $f(x,y)=\frac{x+1}{x^2-y}$ then $f$ is not even defined on $y=x^2$. And the question of the problem is find all regions of $xy-$plane such that Picard's T. holds. But how can I find a rectangle $D$ such that $f$ will be continuous on $D$ if $f$ is not defined on $x=y^2$?

Have I understand something wrong? I am stuck at this. Thansk for any help and explanation.